# ASP Net Core 2.1 создал из шаблона авторизация по базе данных, но нет представлений?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

ASP Net Core 2.1 создал из шаблона авторизация по базе данных. Создались в БД таблицы после миграции EF. Пользователь может регистрироваться, заходить. Но не могу найти где лежат представления и контроллеры по этому пути */Identity/Account/Manage* или по этому пути *Identity/Account/Manage/PersonalData*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нет `view` контроллеров и т.д. и т.п. Или, скажем, как сменить длину пароля для пользователя, переименовать с англ. на русский меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменили создание авторизации по шаблону в базе данных. 
Теперь надо переопределять стандартное представление. Нажимаем по проекту правой кнопкой - добавить - создать шаблонный элемент - слева выбираем пункт удостоверение  - добавить - и тут выбираем какие страницы нам надо переопределить.
[Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)